# Computing the Picard group of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I want to compute the Picard group of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]$, which is not a Dedekind domain. The problem is that I don't even know where to begin.

Any ideas would be helpful.

Thanks

Edit- Since there's some confusion by what I mean by the "Picard group".

$\textit{Definition}$

Let A be an integral domain. Let K denote it's field of fractions. Consider the set of all invertible fractional ideals F(A). Then F(A) forms a group. Consider the subgroup of non-zero principal fractional ideals P(A). So any element in P(A) looks like xA where x $\in$ K$^*$. Then the Picard group of A is defined as F(A)/P(A).

When A is a Dedekind domain, the Picard group coincides with the class group.

Edit 2 - So here's why I'm having a hard time with this problem.

Had $\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{-19}$ been integrally closed, we could proceed using the Minkowski bound and Kummer-Dedekind theory. Unfortunately, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]$ is $\textit{not}$ integrally closed.

The integral closure in it's field of fractions $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-19})$ is actually strictly bigger, given by $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1 + \sqrt{-19}}{2}]$.

And thus, I can't use routine methods to try and understand this group.

Answer (score 1):

In case of imaginary quadratic field, there is a nice correspondence between the Picard group of orders with discriminant $D$ and reduced primitive quadratic form with the same discriminant. More precisely, the form $ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ corresponds to the ideal class of $(a,(-b+\sqrt{D})/2)$.

For more information and proof, consult chapter 7 of the well-known *Primes of the Form $x^2+ny^2$* by David Cox.

---

The order $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]$ has discriminant $-56$, and there are three primitive reduced forms:
$$x^2+19y^2 \qquad 4x^2-2xy+5y^2 \qquad 4x^2+2xy+5y^2$$
they respectively translate to the trivial ideal, $(4,1+\sqrt{-19})$ and $(4,-1+\sqrt{-19})$.

Hence the Picard group of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]$ is cyclic of order $3$ generated by $(4,1+\sqrt{-19})$.

Comment: That's really interesting (for some reason I couldn't find your answer when I wanted to reply. Weird.) I was hoping that I could solve this problem without having to count primitive quadratic forms.

Answer (score -3):

You want to use the Kummer-Dedekind Theorem to factor the prime ideals of norm at most the Minkowski bound.

I recommend you follow 2.6.1 of https://jrsijsling.eu/notes/ant-notes.pdf

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm not sure how to use the theorem though because $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]$ is not a Dedekind domain and it isn't the ring of integers for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-19})$.

Comment: $-19 \equiv 1 \mod 4$, so $\mathcal{O}_K=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, where $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}(1 + \sqrt{-19})$. Can you not simply apply the theorem from there? (Sorry, I don't have a full worked example like this)

Comment: @bounceback Sounds to me like the asker is not referring to $\mathcal O_{\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-19})}$ at all, but rather to the domain of numbers of the form $a + b \sqrt{-19}$ with $a, b \in \mathbb Z$. Thus 20 has two distinct factorizations: $$2^2 \times 5 = (1 - \sqrt{-19})(1 + \sqrt{-19}) = 20.$$ I can't help with this question, though, I'm looking at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PicardGroup.html and not fully understanding it. I'm not looking at the Wikipedia article (first result on the search) to avoid misinformation contamination.

Comment: The class number is 1, so the Picard group is trivial, but I do not yet have a proof. @RobertSoupe Wikipedia is a surprisingly reliable source for mathematics!

Comment: The class number is 1 *if* we have numbers like $$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{-19}}{2}$$ in there. If I've understood user643767 correctly,  we don't. As for Wikipedia, look up math on Wikipediocracy.

Comment: I've provided a definition as to what I mean by the Picard group.

@RobertSoupe Yeah you're correct.